# Mongoose - `find` is not a function

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

There are other similar questions about it but I still didn't find the answer.

Here's my code:

```
// file A
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const sectionSchema = new Schema({
    id: { type: String, required: true },
    color: { type: String, required: true },
    shop: { type: String, requred: true },
});

const Section = mongoose.model("section", sectionSchema);
module.exports = Section;

// file B
const Section = require("../server/models/section");

class Toto {
    save() {
        Section.find() // ERROR: find is not a function
    }
}
```

I'm having an error `find is not a function`
Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: `find()` is for arrays.

Comment: Have you verified what type `Section` actually is? Does it make a difference if you call `Section.find({})`?

Comment: @jarmod how to I check that ? `console.log(typeof(Section))` output's is `function`

Comment: @jarmod `Section.find({})` is doing the same

Comment: Section should be a subclass of mongoose.Model, as far as I can see. If you combine file A and B and remove the potential for import issues, does the code work?

Comment: @jarmod Still the same error if I combine the 2 files

Comment: Try to reinstall mongoose. The first thought was the  proposed solution. It seems a package error

Comment: @JorgeGuerraPires still the same after reinstallation :(

Comment: Try to run outside class. Could it be a doman issue?

Comment: @JorgeGuerraPires Still the same outside a function. What do you mean by domain issue? I'm working locally

Comment: Sometimes, when using JavaScript, we may have some domain issue depending on which version you are using. Since your code seems correct, we must consider the "impossible". Sometimes the obvious can be the answer.

Comment: @JorgeGuerraPires how can I check that?

Comment: This code works fine for me with current mongoose NPM package. The type of Section is function, and console.dir(Section) logs that Section is `[Function: model]` and further lists various query functions like find, findone, merge, replace etc.

Comment: @jarmod wow this is weird ... I'm new to JS so I don't know what to do :/

Comment: @jarmod @JorgeGuerraPires it works if I try directly under my mongoose connection in my server.js : ```const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect(
  process.env.DATABASE_URL,
  { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true }
);

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const sectionSchema = new Schema({
    sectionID: { type: String, required: true },
    color: { type: String, required: true },
    shop: { type: String, requred: true },
});
console.log(mongoose.model("section", sectionSchema).find({}));```

Comment: Are you using Windows???

Comment: Be sure you don't have any naming clashes where, for example, you've named one of your JS source files the same name as a Mongoose, or other, package or class.

Comment: Good point, this is shadowing

Comment: @jarmod @JorgeGuerraPires `React is client side, so create an express server for mongoose, I had the same problem a few hours spent and found a good solution.` Does it means that I can't call mongoose methods from React components?